# How to create a BigQuery UDF function to UNNEST multiple REPEATED levels?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, nested, user-defined-functions, unnest

**Background**: I have a `BigQuery schema` with several `REPEATED` levels and trying create [`UDF functions`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions) to facilitate querying.

**Able to handle 1 level:** when I'm dealing with only 1 REPEATED level I'm able to write the below UDF function which works:

[image]

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION struct_array_struct_scalar(data ANY TYPE) AS (
  (
    SELECT ARRAY_AGG(l1.element.id)
    FROM UNNEST(data.list) as l1
  )
);
```

```
SELECT struct_array_struct_scalar(my_field) as my_field_ids FROM my_table
```

The above works fine and returns an `ARRAY` of ids.

**Struggling with multiple levels:** now when I have multiple nested `REPEATED` fields this is where the challenge arises

[image]

Here the values I'm interested in are nested under  `my_field.list[].element.rates.list[].element.rate.double`. There are only 2 `REPEATED` levels (list[]), everything else is nested under records so using the `.` notation to get them is trivial.

So far I have:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION foo(data ANY TYPE) AS (
  (
    SELECT ARRAY_AGG(l2.element.rate.double)
    FROM UNNEST(
      (SELECT l1.element.rates.list
      FROM UNNEST(data.list) AS l1)
    ) AS l2
  )
);
```

So I have:

- 2 nested subqueries with `UNNEST` to handle the 2 `REPEATED` fields with respective aliases `l1` and `l2`
- `.` notation to go access nested records within those lists

**Although the syntax seems good I get the following error**:

> Scalar subquery produced more than one element

**Q: Can you please give me a clue as to what I need to change to return an ARRAY of rate.double?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope below give you some direction for your problem. (It might need to be modified depending on your real data)

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION foo(data ANY TYPE) AS (
  ARRAY(
    SELECT l2.element.rate.double 
      FROM UNNEST(data.list) l1, UNNEST(l1.element.rates.list) l2
     WHERE l2.element.rate.double IS NOT NULL
  )
);

-- another udf which returns same result as above.
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION foo0(data ANY TYPE) AS ((
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(l2.element.rate.double IGNORE NULLS)
    FROM UNNEST(data.list) l1, UNNEST(l1.element.rates.list) l2
));

SELECT foo(my_field) FROM my_table;
```

**Query results**

[image]

###### Sample Data

[image]

Comment: Great stuff. FYI my data had NULL values and BigQuery would throw `Array cannot have a null element` error but adding `WHERE l2.element.rate.double IS NOT NULL` condition to the select fixed the issue

Comment: @Max, sure you can discard `null` in `WHERE` clause and I've added another implementation which returns same result fyi. kindly check that out as well. thanks.